# Are messages send to gpars actors copied or referenced?

Tags: groovy, actor, gpars

Are messages send to gpars actors copied or referenced? If I send a buffered output stream containing binary data, it's referenced right, or is it copied? How does strings or other kind of data work? Is there some kind of message queues for the actors?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are referenced. GPars actors do not create copies of sent messages automatically.